# SQL SUM, GROUP BY problems

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Why this doesnt work for me? I'm trying to select jobs that are performed by more than 2 employees in each billing unit (OJ).

```
select W.NAME as NAME,
    W.OJ as OJ,
    W.JOB as JOB,
    W.MONTHLY_PAY as MONTHLY_PAY ,
    SUM(W.OJ) AS "SUM"
 from WORKER W
 WHERE W.OJ > 2
 GROUP BY W.IME, W.POSAO, W.MJESECNA_PLACA
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select W.OJ, count(*) as num_workers
from WORKER W
group by W.O
having count(*) > 2;
```

Comment: It is close.. Thank you. But i need to print all work that have more than 2 workers.

Comment: @BrunoBarić . . . I don't think "> 2" is that hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT job
FROM
(
SELECT 
    w.job, w.oj, count(*) workerCount
FROM worker w
GROUP BY w.job, w.oj) t
GROUP BY job
HAVING min(workerCount) > 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But i need to print all work that have more than 2 workers. It doesnt work someway

Comment: Thought you want all work that have more than 2 workers in each Billing Unit.

Comment: Added `GROUP BY job`.

Comment: what means that "t".. stll doesnt work.. i work in oracle compailer

Answer (score 0):

All fields in SELECT clause (except aggregated fields) should be present in GROUP BY clause.

Try below :

```
select W.IME, W.POSAO, W.MJESECNA_PLACA
    SUM(W.OJ) AS "SUM"
 from WORKER W
 WHERE W.OJ > 2
 GROUP BY W.IME, W.POSAO, W.MJESECNA_PLACA
```

Comment: Nemože se tako riješiti jer on uspoređuje W.OJ da li je veće od 2? A treba uzeti sumu